# gcloud App Engine Flexible Strangeness with Docker and Babel

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, babeljs, gcloud

I've been deploying a server side node application to a custom app engine runtime for a few months without any problems. The only half interesting thing about it is that a run babel against the source when I build the container.

In this last few weeks this has been failing intermittently with an error to this effect in the remote build log.

```
import * as deps from './AppFactory';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Leading me to believe that the babel transpilation wasn't happening; though the gcloud cli indicates it is:

```
> node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js src/ -d dist/

src/AppFactory.js -> dist/AppFactory.js
src/Ddl.js -> dist/Ddl.js
src/Helpers.js -> dist/Helpers.js
src/MemoryResolver.js -> dist/MemoryResolver.js
src/Mysql.js -> dist/Mysql.js
src/Schema.js -> dist/Schema.js
src/index.js -> dist/index.js
 ---> 0282c805d5c9
```

In desperation I cat out the dist/index file in the Dockerfile. When I do, I see that indeed no transpilation occurs.

When I create a docker image locally, everything works perfectly.

My Dockerfile follows:

```
# Set the base image to Ubuntu
FROM    gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs:latest

ENV NODE_ENV production

# File Author / Maintainer
# Provides cached layer for node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /src && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /src/

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src

RUN npm run deploy
RUN cat /src/dist/index.js

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Below is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
  ]
}
```

And my vanilla yaml file:

```
service: metrics-api-test
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  NODEPORT: '8080'
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: pwc-sales-demos:us-east1:pawc-sales-demos-sql
```

I've been trying all sorts of variations with babel-register, babel-node. They all work perfectly when I build a local docker image.  They all fail when I deploy to the app engine.

I posted this a few months ago and the issue is starting to plague me again. It started off as an intermittent problem and now it happens every time.  It happens between services and even on different gcloud projects.

Any insight into this gets my appreciation and 150 points.

Comment: can u post package.json file

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, images built on Google servers use the same Dockerfile that you provide.  If the Babel transpilation happens during the image building, it would have to be happening during some step of the Dockerfile you posted here as the base image [gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/blob/master/base/Dockerfile) does not perform any transpilation.  Does the babel transpilation happen during your `npm install` command or `npm run deploy`?  As mentioned previously, it would be helpful to see your **package.json**.

Comment: Yea.  the package file isn't in that state anymore.  I'm near 100% certain that I had all the babel dependencies properly moved to the normal dependencies as opposed to dev.  I'll try to revisit this again when I can.

Comment: Alternatively, you can continue to build the docker images locally if you [push your own images to the Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing) and use [`gcloud app deploy --image-url=<your-gcr-url>`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally getting back to this; it was completely my fault.

I had thought that I had moved all the babel dependencies into the runtime dependency strophe, like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"....
```

But I must have not. All works perfectly with the above and this Dockerfile:

```
FROM    gcr.io/google_appengine/nodejs:latest

ENV NODE_ENV production

# File Author / Maintainer
# Provides cached layer for node_modules
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /src && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /src/

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src

RUN node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js src/ -d dist/
RUN cat dist/index.js
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

No more manually building the file!